# Issue with Fixed Elements in Material Angular Tab

Tags: css, angular-material

When we add an element with position: fixed to the Tab Content, it is positioning the element with respect the Tab Content instead of the Body, any fixes for this? Code Pen attached.

```
.fixed-element {
  position: fixed;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  background: #aaa;
}
```

[Code Pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EjdGvm)

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want the `.fixed-element` in every tab?

Comment: Not in everyTab, in only one Tab for now. But that should be positioned w.r.t Body and not the Tab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`postion: fixed;` under `transform: translate` is not working for the time being, please refer the below link for more info: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=20574

Answer (score 1):

Can you take a look at this [codepen here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YXRrpg) 
I took the content out and then I am displaying the content based on which tab user select. (see `ng-switch`). Hope this helps you. Thank you.
Since I am new too. Let me know If I did some mistake.

My code :**HTML**

```
<div class="tabsdemoDynamicHeight" ng-app="MyApp">
   <md-content class="md-padding">
    <md-tabs  md-dynamic-height="" md-border-bottom=""md-selected="tabs.selectedIndex">
      <md-tab id="tab1" aria-controls="Tab 1" label="one">
      </md-tab>
      <md-tab id="tab2" aria-controls="Tab 2" label="two">
      </md-tab>
      <md-tab id="tab3" aria-controls="Tab 3" label="three">
      </md-tab>
    </md-tabs>

  <md-content class="md-padding">
    <ng-switch on="tabs.selectedIndex">
      <div ng-switch-when="0">
      <!-- put the content of tab 1 here-->  
          <h1 class="md-display-2">Tab One</h1>
          <div class="fixed-element"> Fixed Element</div>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla venenatis ante augue. Phasellus volutpat neque ac dui mattis vulputate. Etiam consequat aliquam cursus. In sodales pretium ultrices. Maecenas lectus est, sollicitudin consectetur felis nec, feugiat ultricies mi.</p>
      </div>
      <div ng-switch-when="1">
          <h1 class="md-display-2">Tab Two</h1>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla venenatis ante augue. Phasellus volutpat neque ac dui mattis vulputate. Etiam consequat aliquam cursus. In sodales pretium ultrices. Maecenas lectus est, sollicitudin consectetur felis nec, feugiat ultricies mi. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam placerat, tortor in ultrices porttitor, orci enim rutrum enim, vel tempor sapien arcu a tellus. Vivamus convallis sodales ante varius gravida. Curabitur a purus vel augue ultrices ultricies id a nisl. Nullam malesuada consequat diam, a facilisis tortor volutpat et. Sed urna dolor, aliquet vitae posuere vulputate, euismod ac lorem. Sed felis risus, pulvinar at interdum quis, vehicula sed odio. Phasellus in enim venenatis, iaculis tortor eu, bibendum ante. Donec ac tellus dictum neque volutpat blandit. Praesent efficitur faucibus risus, ac auctor purus porttitor vitae. Phasellus ornare dui nec orci posuere, nec luctus mauris semper.</p>
          <p>Morbi viverra, ante vel aliquet tincidunt, leo dolor pharetra quam, at semper massa orci nec magna. Donec posuere nec sapien sed laoreet. Etiam cursus nunc in condimentum facilisis. Etiam in tempor tortor. Vivamus faucibus egestas enim, at convallis diam pulvinar vel. Cras ac orci eget nisi maximus cursus. Nunc urna libero, viverra sit amet nisl at, hendrerit tempor turpis. Maecenas facilisis convallis mi vel tempor. Nullam vitae nunc leo. Cras sed nisl consectetur, rhoncus sapien sit amet, tempus sapien.</p>
          <p>Integer turpis erat, porttitor vitae mi faucibus, laoreet interdum tellus. Curabitur posuere molestie dictum. Morbi eget congue risus, quis rhoncus quam. Suspendisse vitae hendrerit erat, at posuere mi. Cras eu fermentum nunc. Sed id ante eu orci commodo volutpat non ac est. Praesent ligula diam, congue eu enim scelerisque, finibus commodo lectus.</p>

      </div>
      <div ng-switch-when="2">

          <h1 class="md-display-2">Tab Three</h1>
          <p>Integer turpis erat, porttitor vitae mi faucibus, laoreet interdum tellus. Curabitur posuere molestie dictum. Morbi eget congue risus, quis rhoncus quam. Suspendisse vitae hendrerit erat, at posuere mi. Cras eu fermentum nunc. Sed id ante eu orci commodo volutpat non ac est. Praesent ligula diam, congue eu enim scelerisque, finibus commodo lectus.</p>

    </div>
      </ng-switch>
  </md-cotent>
     </md-content>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.fixed-element {
  position: fixed;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  background: #aaa;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But any reasons why the fixed element is not working properly?